# How to convert C# console app to Winforms or other GUI?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I have written a long console app (over 1000 lines of code) and I want it to have a GUI. I was wondering if there was a way to quickly convert it to Winforms or other GUI?

I saw this article online that mentions how to convert console apps to Winforms, but it's not helping:

http://saezndaree.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/how-to-redirect-the-consoles-output-to-a-textbox-in-c/

When I followed the instructions on there, I was able to add a Winforms part to my program. But when I compile it, the Winforms does not include the Console app component of the program. My Form.cs includes the Winforms and Program.cs is the console app part with >1000 lines of code that I wrote before. Compiling it, only the part in the Form.cs runs. The Program.cs part doesn't run. For example, I have many "Console.Writeline" and "Console.Readline" parts in the Program.cs, but they run after I add the "Form.cs" to the program

Comment: Please show the code that you have at the moment.  I presume that you've created a new Win Forms project - have you referenced the existing console app (or did you just copy the program.cs to the new project)?

Comment: If you have the whole code of your program in your Program.cs file, you are screwed! That's the worst design I can think of. There is no (easy) way to make use of your code in a GUI. You will have to move your code using classes and objects.

Comment: Although I agree with theghostofc your problem is that you switched the starting point but nowhere in your winform the Program class with your console code is called (btw, 1000 lines is not a big program but if in one class mostly lacks design). What do you have a winforms code so far?

Comment: The code can be seen at https://github.com/jk34/projects1/blob/master/yugioh_consoleapp_C%23

Comment: The code looks like it will be fun to play, but for your own sanity, you need to break your business logic from your display logic and try to abstract things more.

Answer (score 2):

You can not have two entry points in your program. Better to move your 1000 lines of code to a separate class so you have flexibility to either run from console or winforms (depending on which one is set as startup project)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to convert the core functionality to a class library that can be called from both the command line or GUI application whichever is required.

As a quick measure (but weird too) on every event on the GUI application, you may call the command line application too. For this the command line application will receive inputs as parameter and will return output as text which can be shown on the GUI.

> Please take this as a starting point as it may not fully apply in your case.